# Where are the small fuel reservoir tanks on a Cessna P210N?

Tags: fuel-systems, fuel-tanks, cessna-210-centurion

I have looked through the POH and the maintenance manual of the Cessna P210N, both said that the fuel goes from the main tanks into two small reservoir tanks somewhere on the lower side of the fuselage, from there through the fuel tank selector valve to the engine. But neither said exactly ***where*** these tanks are located (They could be below the wings, between the engine and firewall, below the pilot's seats, …). Can you tell me where the fuel reservoir tanks are located on a Cessna P210N ?

EDIT: Also, how much fuel fits into each of the reservoir tanks ?